# Apple TV not showing in iTunes 10 when connected to LAN via Fritz!Box

Tags: networking, macbook, appletv, macbook-air, fritzbox

My setup:

Fritz!Box 7390 International is modem and router (both LAN and WiFI)
Apple TV (1st gen, latest firmware) is connected to LAN port on Fritz!Box
MacBook Air (newest) is connected to other LAN port on Fritz!Box
Fritz!Box also has G/N Wifi network active.

When MacBook and Apple TV are both connected on LAN, iTunes (10, latest version) cannot "see" Apple TV. Apple TV is pingable and reachable using IP-adress or local address appletv.fritz.box. The appletv.local address however does not resolve.

When MacBook is on WiFi and Apple TV is on LAN, MacBook sees Apple TV just fine. It's then also reachable on its appletv.local address.

There's plenty to find about Apple TV not showing in iTunes, but nothing about the LAN/WLAN discrepancy.

What could cause this? Multicasting issues? Any suggestions for a solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Somehow this has fixed itself. The issue just went away for me, Apple TV is now visible whether or not I am on WLAN. No idea what caused it.

Looking at the similar problems posted online, they also state that at one point the Apple TV will just become visible again. Try LAN, WLAN in various combinations if you want. It's quirky, it's weird, but nothing much you can do about it when it hits you.